# Can't create any files/folders on Desktop -- Ubuntu-GNOME

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I am using ubuntu-GNOME 16.04.

I am not able to create any files/folders on my Desktop. I do have a `~/Desktop` directory , but any files created inside that folder are not reflected on my Desktop.

`mkdir ~/Desktop/abcd` creates the folder `abcd` in my `~/Desktop` as expected. But doesn't show up on my Desktop.

I don't even have a right-click menu option to create a file/folder on my Desktop.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I had a similar issue with my Pi running MATE. Don't remember how I fixed it though :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure for Gnome if the Desktop should show items/icons or not using several ways

## Using gnome-tweak-tool

**Install**

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Should look somehow like that
[image]

## Using gsettings from terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons
```

You might need to restart nautilus to finish the change

```
nautilus -q
nautilus
```

Comment: Wow! that was easy. But I still prefer command line. something like `gsettings set org.Something related to this behaviour`

Comment: You could test if `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` works - i got no ubuntu/gnome box handy right now

Comment: It works . Perfect! thankyou very much . That was the exact answer I was looking for. please add this method in your answer as it requires to tool :-)

Comment: I added the second method as well

Comment: I don't think there's a need to restart nautilus.